# inline style vs jQuery .css

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I came across an example of revealing a hidden div which is inside an element using css only

```
<style type="text/css">
#shopCart:hover .shopCartDetail {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<div id="shopCart">
Shop Cart
<div class="shopCartDetail"><style>.shopCartDetail {display:none}</style>
    This is Shop Cart Detail</div>
</div>
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/7DRTD/

In my scenario, the style display:none is created by jQuery. Revealing the hidden div using hover does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2mtF/

What can be the issue here? The html code looks same, both examples add inline style to the div.

The question is: why does the second scenario not work?

Thank you.

Comment: You posted the same JSFiddle twice.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your problem but if you're talking about jQuery hover and you're dynamically creating that object, you should use "live" instead of "hover" so when the object is created, the live event will bind to it.

Comment: Why have you got the separate `<style>` block inside your `<div>`? You know you can define both settings in the same block: http://jsfiddle.net/7DRTD/5/ Doing it with jQuery also works: http://jsfiddle.net/7DRTD/6/

Comment: @vucko sorry, it should be now ok

Comment: @nnnnn I used <style> to emulate inline class

Comment: this is an interesting one.  It's trivial to add the hover some other way, but why does adding the css via jquery invalidate the hover defined in the css?

Comment: BTW:  placing `<style></style>` tags **anywhere** outside of the `<head>` section is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general sense, styles applied directly to an individual element take precedence over settings from the stylesheet. This is (part of) the "cascading" effect that is the "C" in "CSS". So when you hide the element with jQuery with the following in your document ready:

```
$(".shopCartDetail").css("display","none");
```

...it is equivalent to adding `style="display:none"` directly to the element, which has the same "problem": http://jsfiddle.net/Z2mtF/2/

This is *not* the same as applying a class to the element, which is what your "emulation" above was doing with the `<style>` element inside the `<div>`.

So the hover rule isn't important enough to take effect. One way to fix this is to *make* the hover rule important:

```
#shopCart:hover .shopCartDetail
{
    display: block !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z2mtF/1/

Settings in the stylesheet marked as `!important` will take precedence over the inline style attributes.

Note that it's tidier if you use `.show()` and `.hide()` instead of explicitly setting the `display` property via the `.css()` method.